# Flask/Python - Passing dropdown list choice into function

Tags: html, python-2.7, flask

I'm learning flask and Python along w/ HTML and CSS. I've got a Flask template to render a dropdown.

What I need to do is this: When you select a value from the dropdown/picklist, print that out on the same page. if I then select a new value in the picklist, print that value, etc. etc.

I can get the picklist in the template but can't get that value passed back into the template.

Below is my code.

```
{% block content %}
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">     
            <select name="Item_1">
                {% for y in obj %}
                <option value="{{ y }}">{{ y }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>   
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <!-- THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO PRINT THE VALUE {{ y }} AS SOON AS I SELECT IT -->
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

and the app.py code

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    svc = beatbox.Client() 
    svc.login(login, pw) 
    desc = svc.describeSObjects('Opportunity')
    listOfObjects = getObjects()

    #BELOW IS THE SECTION I'M CONFUSED ABOUT, HOW DO I GET printValue INTO THE TEMPLATE DYNAMICALLY?
    printValue = request.form.get['Item_1']

    return render_template("indexes.html",
    obj=listOfObjects,
    #printValue = printValue)
```

Comment: `request.form.get['Item_1']` should be `request.form.get('Item_1')` (Parenthesis rather than brackets).  Otherwise, what problems are you running into?  If you use `{{ printValue }}` where you want `y` to show up is it not showing up, or do you want to make the change without a full page refresh ... or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking for is when you change the value on the client to update the html with the selected value. For this you need to add a bit of jquery javascript to achieve this. Basically you want dynamically update the html.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Scroll down to see the demo.